# How to get the frame rate using wxGLCanvas for linux environment?

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets, video-card, wxglcanvas

I am new learner. I want to know about to How to get the frame rate using wxGLCanvas for linux environment? Have you any idea and code about it? Please help..